# How to install libpq-dev on fedora?

Tags: fedora, c, postgresql, dnf

I'm trying to install libpq-dev on fedora using the command below:

```
sudo dnf install libpq-dev
```

but the result is:

```
No match for argument: libpq-dev
Error: Unable to find a match: libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package name is `libpq-devel`:

```
sudo dnf install libpq-devel
```

[Description](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-x86_64/libpq-devel-11.2-2.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html) :

> libpq-devel - Development files for building PostgreSQL client tools

> The `libpq` package provides the essential shared library for any PostgreSQL
> client program or interface.  You will need to install this package to build any package or any clients that need to connect to a PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Is this as same as libpq-dev in work?

Comment: “libpq-dev” is a Debian (and clones) name for the development headers for PostgreSQL’s libpq library. Fedora and Debian don’t use the same package names, and they aren’t identical in what they ship, so it might be helpful if you say what “in work” means?